# remove category label in catplot

Tags: stata, catplot

Can you remove the category label in `catplot`? (`ssc install catplot`)

I am trying to plot a single category, e.g.

```
sysuse auto, clear
catplot foreign rep78 if rep78 == 3, recast(bar)
```

and I want to remove the "3" from the x-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
catplot foreign if rep78 == 3, recast(bar)
```

would seem a simpler approach.